# Using Nunjucks in the browser, how do I only request a template once to iterate on using different values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nunjucks

I am rendering a Nunjucks template multiple times in the browser:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/products',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    var $tableBody = $('#products-table-body');

    response.products.forEach(function(product) {
      $tableBody.append(
        nunjucks.render( '_item-row.html', { id: product.id, name: product.name } )
      );
    });
  }
});
```

That is creating an HTTP request for each iteration which just receives the same template each time, which seems unnecessary if I just want to use the same template to insert different values for each iteration.

[image]

How can I only request the template once and then use that single template request to fill in the values in each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful [Nunjucks documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html), I figured it out.

```
var env = new nunjucks.Environment(new nunjucks.WebLoader('../views'));

$.ajax({
  url: '/products',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    var $tableBody = $('#products-table-body');

    var template = env.getTemplate('_item-row.html');

    response.products.forEach(function(product) {
      $tableBody.append(
        nunjucks.render( template, { id: product.id, name: product.name } )
      );
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice. But where do you get the `nunjucks` object from? This code is client side right?

Comment: Yup. Just install it using NPM and then include it on your page in various ways: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html